# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next code that i want to use to validate private routing:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from '../../routing/routes';

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    // TODO: user verification
    let user = 1;

    const authComponentResolver = props => {
        const authorizedComponent = <Component {...props} />
        const redirectToAuthComponent = <Redirect to={{ pathname: routes.login.path, state: { from: props.location } }} />

        if (user !== undefined) {
            return authorizedComponent;
        } else {
            return redirectToAuthComponent;
        }
    }

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={authComponentResolver} />
    );
}
```

But it throws the next error:

```
./src/components/auth/private-route.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

I cant understand why, but the next code works:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from '../../routing/routes';

export default function PrivateRoute(a) {
    // TODO: user verification
    let user = 1;

    const authComponentResolver = props => {
        const authorizedComponent = <a.component {...props} />
        const redirectToAuthComponent = <Redirect to={{ pathname: routes.login.path, state: { from: props.location } }} />

        if (user !== undefined) {
            return authorizedComponent;
        } else {
            return redirectToAuthComponent;
        }
    }

    return (
        <Route {...a} render={authComponentResolver} />
    );
}
```

Can someone explain me why first version fails to compile? Both version do the same i think.

Here is the way i call the component:

```
const DashboardRoutes = () => (
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path={routes.root.path} component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute path={routes.dashboard.path} component={Dashboard} />

        <PrivateRoute exact path={routes.persons.path} component={Persons} />
        <PrivateRoute path={routes.personsNew.path} component={NewPerson} />

        <PrivateRoute exact path={routes.branchOffice.path} component={BranchOffices} />
        <PrivateRoute path={routes.personsNew.path} component={NewPerson} />

        <PrivateRoute component={Error404} />
    </Switch >
);
```

In the console i have this error:

```
VM911 main.chunk.js:116 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Linter.parseResults (Users/groupon/Proyectos/Uselessscat/reservas-client/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/Linter.js:121)
    at Linter.printOutput (Users/groupon/Proyectos/Uselessscat/reservas-client/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/Linter.js:85)
    at cache (Users/groupon/Proyectos/Uselessscat/reservas-client/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cacheLoader.js:46)
    at Users/groupon/Proyectos/Uselessscat/reservas-client/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:122
    at Gunzip.cb (Users/groupon/Proyectos/Uselessscat/reservas-client/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:47)
    at Gunzip.zlibBufferOnEnd (zlib.js:131)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:203)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63)
    at Object../src/components/auth/private-route.js (VM911 main.chunk.js:116)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM909 bundle.js:786)
    at fn (VM909 bundle.js:151)
    at Module../src/routing/module-router.js (VM911 main.chunk.js:1098)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM909 bundle.js:786)
    at fn (VM909 bundle.js:151)
    at Module../src/routing/router.js (VM911 main.chunk.js:1226)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM909 bundle.js:786)
    at fn (VM909 bundle.js:151)
    at Module../src/index.js (VM911 main.chunk.js:787)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM909 bundle.js:786)
    at fn (VM909 bundle.js:151)
    at Object.0 (VM911 main.chunk.js:2552)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM909 bundle.js:786)
    at checkDeferredModules (VM909 bundle.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (VM909 bundle.js:33)
    at VM911 main.chunk.js:1
```

but it is indecipherable :(

Thanks.

Comment: one difference both did differently is `rest` doesn't contain `component` and `a` does contain `component`, maybe if you debug it it might be the cause

Comment: Could you show a sandbox to see the error? [Works fine](https://codesandbox.io/embed/infallible-worker-4x6u4) using [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) props.

Comment: what is your `eslint-loader` version??

Comment: @Panther running `npm list eslint-loader` prints `react-scripts@3.1.2 -> eslint-loader@3.0.0`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-scripts` version `3.1.2` or any above `3.0.1`, you may need to downgrade to version `3.0.1` as it seems to work fine. See the [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7753)

Comment: is this issue fixed for 3.4+?

Comment: Hi @Amacelia, I've not had the chance to test this recently but the GitHub issue mentioned they've got a fix. You could give it a try if you're currently using it and share here

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be `eslint-loader` build error - please take a look at [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader/pull/294). Try updating to newest version of eslint-loader and then it should work. If you look at [latest version](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader/blob/fce6f88b3f35b4996fce96768aedfe51288cdb07/src/Linter.js#L122) of `Linter.js`, you'll see that `parseResults` method now has `if` check before calling `forEach`.

Comment: I tried, but im using the lastest version of react-scripts. I tried to update the eslint-loader dependency of react-script in `package-lock.json` but doesn't work :(

Comment: You don't change package-lock but package.json.

Answer (score 1):

This error from `eslint` of `react-scripts`, so my solution is disabled `eslint`.

- Step 1: `yarn add customize-cra react-app-rewired @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators --dev`
- Step 2: At file `config-overrides.js`:

```
const { override, disableEsLint } = require("customize-cra");        
module.exports = override(
   disableEsLint()
);
```

- Step 3: Update script at file `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. Was having a bad time, solving this out.

I tried downgrading to react-scripts: 3.0.1,acc. to some solutions on the web. Didn't work.

What worked for me --> In my case, I observed, Webpack minified my public\index.html file.

After clearing out the minified index.html and writing the regular index.html ,for React. All the errors/issues went away. And now, everything is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Issues I was facing :

- Most changes in the code are not being reflected, in the dev server.
- The error startWorkingOnPEndingInteractions was popping up every time the dev server loaded.
- All of this went away , when I started afresh with a new public/index.html file

Hope this helps. I love the OS community.