# Rest parameters produces an error in my react-bootstrap component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This always works for me but for some reason, it does not work in my react-bootstrap component and this is confusing, rest parameter `{classes, ...props}` cause the code to throw an error and don't know why??

When i tried to reproduce the error in **codesandbox** everything worked ok , but the error still in my machine even after creating many new projects and removing all packages that can affect code till i reached to the point that i have created a very basic project i uploaded it on github [here](https://github.com/saher-elgendy/demo)

Just importing the `ReusableDropdown` component from **dropdown.js** file produced a type error and react says that the error happens in the component itself not inside the parent component:

```
./src/reusable/dropdown.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

This should work and i am sure the error has no relation to the syntax, that's a kind of weird error!!

**PS:**
You need to install react-bootstrap and bootstrap as dependencies to be able to reproduce the error

Comment: I can't see how `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` could be related to an **object**, since objects don't have `forEach` ... unless there's some transpiling going on

Comment: i uploaded the code on github and the link is in the question!

Comment: yes ... you did ... that's not how SO works

Comment: believe me i am so confused about that error, i am used to that syntax and it never produced any error before, now it does!!

Comment: but that code still throw the same error with me

Comment: does the error show which line of the code throws the error?

Comment: when i remove the spread syntax and just used ```props``` instead of ```{...props}``` it worked ok, also logging ```{...props}``` logged the right object with no errors

Comment: and one of the `props` properties is `text`?

Comment: yes just for experiment!!

Comment: and `classes` has a property called `toggle`? - is this a runtime error?

Comment: yes, but all of these props are for experiment, i am used to defined a parameter for every component to be like this ```{classes, ...props}``` so i can create an object for classes to collect them in one place

Comment: it is a build error

Answer (score 1):

It could be an off-topic, but, since I saw there is no `classes` in `<ReusableDropdown>` component,

```
<ReusableDropdown text="his"/>
```

I want to suggest adding defaultProps like following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default ({classes = [], ...props}) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
       <Dropdown.Toggle className={classes.toggle}>{props.text}</Dropdown.Toggle>
       <Dropdown.Menu>
         <Dropdown.Item>hi</Dropdown.Item>
       </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Or, you can check null value

```
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle className={classes && classes.toggle}>
    {props.text}
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item>hi</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

And, I'm understanding that `Dropdown.Toggle` requires `id` prop. Could you check required props as well?

Comment: Thank you but this is not the answer of my question, classes should work without a default value , but my question is about why spread syntax cause a that weird error

Comment: As I understand, props should be an object in your code. Can you check this code `<Dropdown.Toggle className={classes.toggle}>{props && props.text}</Dropdown.Toggle>` ?

Comment: any way thank you, i appreciate your trial to help!

Answer (score 1):

@Jaromanda X @Misol Goh   Thanks for trying to help

after many hours trying to debug, i found this thread that answered my question

[Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161324/cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined-in-react)

**Solution 1:**

adding the following to package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2"
  }
```

**Solution 2:**

downgrade to 3.0.1 version of react-scripts as the newer version caused that error for many users